# Maya xGen data has offset while rendering in Katana with Renderman

Tags: graphics, animation

Has someone noticed the offset in katana renderman, while using the interactive grooming of Maya 2017 and export the xgen data as alembic?

I tried following the steps mentioned in the renderman official site https://rmanwiki.pixar.com/display/RFK/XGen+in+Katana

But the offset is still observed between the driver mesh and the xgen baked out curves.

Any help or link that explains the resolve for this issue would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is blatantly off topic.

Comment: Sure. Else we can migrate this to more relevant resource as I see few of the recent up-vote for the answer that I posted recently? This way it will still help someone facing similar issue with xgen of Maya.

Comment: If you know a Stack Exchange site where this question is **on-topic**, you can flag the question for *moderator attention* and **write** a message requesting migration there.

Answer (score 1):

One of the workaround that fixes this issue - 
Switch or convert the b-spline (which is default curve type) of maya x-gen guide curves to bezier curve before exporting as alembic